# How does angular work with rails asset digests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

When requesting an asset (image, js, css) with angularjs (or anywhere other than a rails view), digests are obviously not appended.

So, while I may request foo.jpg from angularjs, the asset on the server is foo-bd6aebc90ce9117ca17a26ee61acc1be.jpg, so it's obviously not found.

What's the right way to handle this (other than setting `config.assets.digest = false` in the environment ... which seems wrong)?